# How to letting service know the current user name

Tags: linux, upstart, login-name

There is a daemon running as root by upstart in Ubuntu.
I have to know the login user name or uid on a daemon.

Although I have searched and tested the command or function like whoami, who am i and geteuid, I have not gotten the result what I want.

Can anybody let me know the solution?

Comment: shouldn't run upstart as root?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to know the user who is running the daemon?

Comment: Your question is not so clear.If you want to know the daemon who is running then you can try `ps -aux | grep process_name`.

Answer (score 1):

No users are logged in at the time the startup scripts are run.

Typically, daemons are started by `root`, but sometimes, they use a dedicated user ID either because the software is written that way, or because the startup scripts set them up this way.  For example, on Debian-based distros, the web server runs as `www-data` so that if anybody hacks the web server somehow, they will have very limited access to the system.  But how exactly this is configured depends on which daemon and what its startup script and configuration looks like.

If it's your own daemon and you didn't write it or configure it to switch user IDs, it will be running as `root`.

If your daemon is some sort of server and it needs to know at runtime which client is connecting, (you really need to rephrase your question but) that's mainly a function of how the client connects to the server, not of how the server is started.

Answer (score 0):

A small script like this may solve your problem

```
echo "uid is ${UID}"
echo "username is ${USERNAME}"
```